# adding database results to text view dynamically

Tags: android, database, android-layout

i have marks and class in database now i want to create textviews dynamically set the reults from database to textview ho can i do it

```
private void displaymarks() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor c=marksdb.rawQuery("SELECT class,marks FROM  markstb where class='"+clas+"' ",null );
    c.moveToFirst();
     if(c!=null)
     {
      do{
        int c1= c.getColumnIndex("class");
        int c2=c.getColumnIndex("marks");
        s1 = c.getString(c1);
        s2 = c.getString(c2);

      }while(c.moveToNext());

      };
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `ListView`? And on a side note - don't call `c.moveToFirst()` before checking to see if `c` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tvClass=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.class);
TextView tvMarks=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.marks);
while(c.moveToNext())
{
  tvClass.setText(s1);
  tvMarks.setText(s2);
}
```

Comment: it is just a prototype you can add your logic to do in what ever manner you want

Comment: i wanna add textviews dynamically using a loop

Comment: while is a loop but you can use for instead

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai as sqounk said listview is better option to have your textviews inside listview or any other view like grid view,if you just want to add dynamically textviews you can do
 `while(c.moveToNext())
 {
  TextView class=new TextView(this);
  TextView marks=new TextView(this);
 
  classs.setText(s1);
  marks.setText(s2);
 }`